# Sympy: Using solve() to solve for an equality

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica, sympy

I am currently starting to learn python to replace some of the commercial software that I use for university work because I'm trying to use more open-source software. Basically I am trying to do in python what I already did in Wolfram-Mathematica, the code of which you can see here: [Mathematica Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rBe2.png). The field to which I am applying this is waveguide optics.

The problem I have is that when I try to reproduce the 10th line in Mathematica in Python. Basically you are supposed to solve equation 'b' for the effective refractive index (Neff) by reading the value b off of a graph. In this case the value is equal to 0.18 but using this as an equality in the last line in Python gives me an empty list so the item with index 1 doesn't exist.

```
import sympy as sp
sp.init_printing()

nAir=1;nInP = 3.17; nInGaAsP = 3.37;wl=1.55e-6;
n,theta,n0,n1,n2,Neff,d,Lambda = sp.symbols('n theta n0 n1 n2 Neff d lambda')

k0=2*sp.pi/Lambda
k=k0*n
beta=sp.cos(theta)*k
V=k0*d*sp.sqrt(n1**2-n0**2)
a=((n0**2-n2**2)/(n1**2-n0**2))
b=(Neff**2-n0**2)/(n1**2-n0**2)

aysmm1 = a.subs({n0:nInP,n1:nInGaAsP,n2:nAir})
aysmm1

d1=400e-9
Vparam1=V.subs({Lambda:wl,d:d1,n1:nInP,n0:nInGaAsP})

sp.solve(b.subs({n0:nInP,n1:nInGaAsP})==0.18,Neff)[1]
```

The only way around this that I have found is to replace the last line with

```
sp.solve(b.subs({n0:nInP,n1:nInGaAsP})-0.18,Neff)[1]
```

Since it automatically assumes that the given expression is equal to 0. But I was wondering if there is a way to use the sp.solve function with an equality as shown in the first code snippet. And maybe is there a way to automatically assume that Neff is larger than 0? So I don't have to specify the index of the list?

Thanks in advance.

PS: Does anyone know if you can use Greek letters as symbols in Python like I do in Mathematica for lambda?

Comment: This looks like it has the answer to your main question: https://docs.sympy.org/1.5.1/tutorial/gotchas.html#tutorial-gotchas-equals

Comment: For the third question, you need to use `lamda` rather that `lambda` as that's a reserved keyword in python

Comment: For the second question, you can state assumptions when you create the symbol, e.g. `Neff = sp.symbols('Neff', positive=True)`